# GMSServicesException', reason: 'Google Maps SDK for iOS must be initialized via

Tags: swift3, xcode8

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'GMSServicesException', reason: 'Google Maps SDK for iOS must be initialized via [GMSServices provideAPIKey:...] prior to use'

Answer (score 12):

import google map as written below

```
import GoogleMaps
```

get Api key by create app using following link
https://console.developers.google.com/

write below code in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method of `AppDelegate`

```
GMSServices.provideAPIKey("your App Id")
```

that's it

Comment: This works for people who only have the `AppDelegate.swift` file instead of the `AppDelegate.m/.h` file.  Also think you meant to say "Your App API Key", instead of "Your App Id".